# Negative Dimensions Are Not Allowed When Merging Two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, merge

When merging two DataFrames, I'm getting the following error:

*pandas/src/join.pyx in pandas.algos.left_outer_join (pandas/algos.c:46783)()
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed*

Here's the line that's throwing it:

```
badges = pd.merge(left, right, how="inner", on="year").drop_duplicates()
```

The shapes of the two DataFrames are (227630, 5) (227630, 4), though it seems that shouldn't matter. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of data that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Can you find the smallest failing case?  (`left = left.iloc[:200000]` etc. and decrease the numbers.)

Comment: So, interestingly enough this runs fine with 10,000 rows from each dataframce and turns into a memory error with 100,000 rows from from each. That may be underlying issue, I'll try this somewhere other than ipython notebook on a laptop

Comment: were you able to solve this?