# Causes of negative dimensions are not allowed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What would be possible causes of this error:

```
 negative dimensions are not allowed
```

I am using `crosstab` on a pandas data frame with 8 million rows, it works fine up to 2 million rows, and it throws this error when the size of data gets larger.

I tried to achieve what I want to achieve (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788179/converting-long-table-to-wide-and-creating-columns-according-to-the-rows/46788434#46788434) question) using `unstack`, and I get exactly the same error.

Can anyone give any hint on this?  I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518009/reason-of-valueerror-negative-dimensions-are-not-allowed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973781/negative-dimensions-are-not-allowed-when-merging-two-dataframes), but they were not helpful enough

Comment: do it chunk by chunk and concat the result

Comment: @Wen: good idea, but there must be a reason why it is behaving this way, do you know why?

Comment: Tyr type `df.columns.nunique()` and `df.index.nunique()
` what is the output ?

Comment: @Wen:
`data_filtered.index.nunique() = 8699839` 


`data_filtered.columns.nunique() = 6`